# Take the screenshot of captured image in surfaceview

Tags: android

I opened the camera using surface view.

Imageview in MainActivity. 
when i click the imageview Camera open and i click the textview(Capture) in surfaceview the image saved into memory and set into imageview.

Between that two actions i get confirm from user whether the captured image is ok or not(Ok or cancel).

If user click ok the captured image is set into imageview. 
If user click cancel the camera will open again.

That confirm screen appear with captured image and two buttons(ok and cancel)

My code to open camera in surface view

```
package com.example.androidsurfaceviewexample;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    TextView testView;
    Camera camera;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    PictureCallback rawCallback;
    ShutterCallback shutterCallback;
    PictureCallback jpegCallback;
    public static boolean front = false;
    Intent intent = null;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        front = extras.getBoolean("front");
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    String filePath=String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    FirstActivity.photo = true;
                    intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    //extras.putByteArray("path", data);
                     extras.putString("path", filePath);
                    extras.putString("front", "" + front);
                    intent.putExtras(extras);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Picture Saved", 2000)
                        .show();
                refreshCamera();
            }
        };
    }
    public void captureImage(View v) throws IOException {
        // take the picture
        camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
    }

    public void refreshCamera() {
        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }
        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }
        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        } else {
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
        }
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.
        refreshCamera();
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
        // open the camera
            System.out.println("camera id"+""+getCamera());
            if(front)
            {
                int frontExist=getCamera();
                if(frontExist==1)
                camera = getFrontFacingCamera();
                else
                    camera = Camera.open();
            }
            else
            camera = Camera.open();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // check for exceptions
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }
        // Camera.Parameters param;
        // param = camera.getParameters();
        // modify parameter
        // param.setPreviewSize(352, 288);
        // camera.setParameters(param);

        try {
            // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw
            // the preview.
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // check for exceptions
            System.err.println(e);
            return;

        }

    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // stop preview and release camera
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }

    Camera getFrontFacingCamera() throws NoSuchElementException {
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        for (int cameraIndex = 0; cameraIndex < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); cameraIndex++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraIndex, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                try {
                    return Camera.open(cameraIndex);
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Can't find front camera.");
    }

    int getCamera()
    {
        int f=0;
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        for (int cameraIndex = 0; cameraIndex < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); cameraIndex++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraIndex, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                try {
                    f=1;
                    break;
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
                f=0;
        }
        return f;
    }

}
```

Surfaceview Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.androidsurfaceviewexample.CameraActivity" >


    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.66" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/capture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="captureImage"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Capture"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can i take the entire view of captured image from surfaceview?

Please help to solve this...

Comment: you want to only captrue the visible image from the surfaceView ?

Comment: @HugoGresse thanks for your reply. i want the view while clicking capture. That is captured image...

Answer (score -1):

If you just wan't to have the exact image of the displayed SurfaceView pixels, you can use the following method :

```
/**
 * Take a screenshot of the view
 * @param view the view to capture
 * @return the bitmap representing the pixels of the given view
 */
@Nullable
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View view) {
    try {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError error){
        TeadsLog.d(LOG_TAG, "Out of Memory while loadBitmapFromView");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you wan't to take the capture, call it like `ViewUtils.loadBitmapFromView(surfaceView);`. Assuming you will put this method in an utils class name `ViewUtils`